# Groupby Multiple date time period

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table, which represents the number of times a particular event has occurred on a per day basis.

| date | event | occurrences |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-01 | jumping | 10 |
| 2020-08-20 | walking | 7 |
| 2016-01-01 | swimming | 1 |
| 2020-05-01 | jumping | 5 |

I want to group by three different time periods:

1. recent events which have occurred at least once in the last
   3 months from the current date
2. old events which have not occurred in the last  3 months from the current date but have
   occurred at least once in the last year from current date
3. very old events which have not occurred in the last year from current date

The resulting table should be

| event | state |
| --- | --- |
| jumping | recent |
| walking | old |
| swimming | swimming |

How do I go about doing this efficiently in BigQuery SQL?

Answer (score 2):

Try `max` and `case` statements:

```
with testdata as (
  select date '2021-02-01' as date, 'jumping' as event, 10 as occurences union all
  select date '2020-08-20', 'walking', 7 union all
  select date '2016-01-01', 'swimming', 1 union all
  select date '2020-05-01', 'jumping', 5
)
select 
  event,
  case
    when max(date) < date_sub(current_date(), interval 1 year) then 'very old'
    when max(date) < date_sub(current_date(), interval 3 month) then 'old'
    else 'recent'
  end as state
from testdata
where occurences > 0
group by event
```

[image]

Comment: I doubt `occurrences > 0` is really needed.  I get the idea a row is in the data only when there are occurrences (although the OP is not clear on this).